# C# How to implement admin panels that control users and roles ability to access controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm new to C# and have hit a wall when it comes to authorization.

Until now I have used tags like `[Authorize(Roles ="Admin, Manager")]`, but now I have to figure out a way to implement admin pages that can pick controller methods from a list and grant access to users or roles to use them.

I have seen possible solutions to the issue such as Claim-based or Action-based authorization but am not sure if they provide the solution I need.
I understand that I most likely need two approaches to the issue(one for users and one for groups of users), put I can't figure out how to make the link between each method an the target without using the `[Authorize]` attribute throughout the controllers.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: And why don't you do it the other way around and assign user(groups) to Controller methods?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `[Authorize]`? Use this attribute with claims-based authorization, where claim is controller name and register custom policies, which requires those claims, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand your question properly. Maybe provide a proper use case! 
But as far as I understand, you have to use claims/roles to verify which user has access to which resource. Having said that, if you want to know the claims of an authorized user, you can do it various ways. You can get the "User" claims through the user object for your controllers by accessing it through `this.User`. In some cases when that is not possible. You can also get it through `Threads`.

Edit: Now that I am at my Desk, some sample code:

Method 1:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize(Roles = "Superadmin, Admin, User")]
```

Method 2:

```
if (this.User.IsInRole(UserRole.Superadmin.ToString()))
{
    // Special code for SuperAdmin
}
```

Method 3:

```
// This can be used where you don't have access to this.User
var userName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; // Identity has all the claims
User user = _userRepository.Query(x => x.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();

if (user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == UserRole.Superadmin.ToString()))
{
     // Special code for SuperAdmin
}
```

P.S.: I am new to C# as well. Just been a week. :)